# Download files from S3 as Zip using Php

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I am working on Php Laravel application. I have the below UI
[image]

The selected files should be downloaded as a zip file by clicking the download button at the top. These files are stored on Amazon S3

Answer (score 0):

You could try https://www.cloudzipinc.com/ that will create a zip file in your bucket, that contains your desired file folders, then share the url to download the zip.  I used cloudzip to zip and distribute a digital catalog's files from S3.